# Getting JSON response from Cognito log in endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito for my authentication flow. When I log in using the incorrect credentials, I do not get a JSON response hence I can not use it to make some UI changes (show error message etc)

**Login.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

import Logo from "../../images/logo.png";
import LoginImage from "../../images/login.png";
import Google from "../../images/google.png";
import Apple from "../../images/apple.png";
import Facebook from "../../images/facebook.png";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import UserPool from "../../userpool";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // const [authResponse, setAuthResponse] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = new CognitoUser({
      Username: username,
      Pool: UserPool,
    });

    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: username,
      Password: password,
    });

    user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log("onSuccess:", data);
      },
      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.log("onFailure:", err);
      },
      newPasswordRequired: (data) => {
        console.log("newPasswordRequired:", data);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-form-container">
        <img src={Logo} alt="logo" className="login-logo" />
        <div className="login-form">
          <h3 className="main-message"> Log In To Your Account </h3>
          <TextField
            id="standard-basic"
            label="Email/Number"
            variant="standard"
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setUsername(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            id="standard-basic"
            label="Password"
            variant="standard"
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPassword(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <div className="forgot-checkbox">
            <FormControlLabel
              value="end"
              control={<Checkbox />}
              label="Remember me"
              labelPlacement="end"
            />
            <Link to="/forgotpassword" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <p className="forgot-password"> Forgot Password? </p>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#21409A" }}
            onClick={onSubmit}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
          <div className="social-logins">
            <img src={Google} alt="social login" />
            <img src={Apple} alt="social login" />
            <img src={Facebook} alt="social login" />
          </div>
          <p className="registerhere">
            Don't have an account?
            <Link to="/register" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <span className="register-here"> Register here!</span>
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="privacypolicy">
          <p>Privacy Policy </p>
          <p>•</p>
          <p> Terms of Use</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={LoginImage} alt="img" className="login-img" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Response:**

[image: Response from Cognito]

How can I use this response in my return and render components such as error messages on my UI?

Comment: What is the output of `typeof(err)`?

Comment: The code is not running at all. It gives an issue on .resetPassword and does not move forward